# VB.NET - MYSQL - Utilizar 2 querys con un executequery?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

quería ver si me pueden ayudar en lo siguiente: tengo un método que me actualiza los datos de una tabla, me funciona bien, pero el tema es que también necesito que se actualice al mismo tiempo otra tabla (el dato es en común en ambas tablas, un ID numérico), pero no me funciona llamar a otro executequery() que tendría asignada la ejecución de una segunda query que actualizara la otra tabla...

el código del método que tengo es este

```vb
conexionMYSQL = New MySqlConnection

    conexionMYSQL.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;User Id=soporte;database=db_incidencias_muniquel;password=123")

    Try
        'Limpia los errores anteriores
        Me.erpSoporte.Clear()

        conexionMYSQL.Open()

        'VALIDACION DE CONTROLES
        If Me.ValidateChildren And cmbEstado.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then 'And cmbDepartamento.SelectedIndex.Equals(0)

            'Dim query2 As String=("UPDATE tbl_incidencias SET id_nivel='3',id_tipo_solicitud= '5',id_categoria= '1',id_subcategoria= '2',id_registro= '1',id_registro_soporte= '4',id_metodo_ingreso= '2',id_estado= '1',fecha_registro= '2018-04-20',detalle_incidencia= " "'detalle con id de funcionario'" WHERE id_incidencia=3")

            Dim query1 As String = ("UPDATE tbl_incidencias SET id_estado=@id_estado WHERE id_incidencia=@id_incidencia")

            Dim query As String = ("UPDATE tbl_acciones_incidencia SET id_estado=@id_estado, comentarios_accion=@comentarios_accion WHERE id_accion=@id_accion")


            comando = New MySqlCommand(query, conexionMYSQL)

            comando1 = New MySqlCommand(query, conexionMYSQL)

            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_estado", Convert.ToInt32(txtIdEstado.Text))
            comando1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_estado", Convert.ToInt32(txtIdEstado.Text))
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comentarios_accion", txtComentario.Text)
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_accion", Convert.ToInt32(lblIdAccion.Text))
            comando1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_incidencia", Convert.ToInt32(lblIdIncidencia.Text))

            dr = comando.ExecuteReader

            dr = comando1.ExecuteReader

            'MENSAJE DE CONFIRMACION
            MsgBox("LA ACCIÓN CORRECTIVA A SIDO REGISTRADA E INFORMADA DE FORMA EXITOSA")

            'restaurarControles()

            dgvIndenciasInformadas.Refresh()

            conexionMYSQL.Close()

            'Me.Dispose()
        Else
            'FALLO LA VALIDACION DE LOS CONTROLES
            MsgBox("VERIFIQUE LOS ERRORES MARCADOS EN EL FORMULARIO")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
    End Try
```

agradezco desde ya a todos sus comentarios y ayuda....

Comment: para hacer un update, no debes usar `ExcuteReader`, sino `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: y aca hay un solo query... donde esta el que no anda?

Comment: HOLA gbianchi, modifique el codigo del metodo en la pregunta :)

Comment: Como ya lo dijo @pikoh debes cambiar el `ExecuteReader` por un `ExecuteNonQuery`. Por otro lado corrige el msgbox, tiene un error de ortografía es: "LA ACCIÓN CORRECTIVA HA..."

Comment: pero usando datareader se puede utilizar executenonquery?  hago el cambio y me marca error: Error 1 Un valor de tipo 'Integer' no se puede convertir en 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader

Comment: resuelto lo del eror 1, le pase una variable integer al executenonquery

Comment: comando y comando1 tienen el mismo query como parametro. Deberias pasarle a comando1 el query1

Comment: No necesitas el datareader ya que es una consulta de ejecucion, de hecho no necesitas asignar el valor de la instruccion executenonquery a nada a menos que quieras saber el resultado de la operacion